# Tenho um sistema MVC preciso fazer uma requisição em ajax para exibir conteúdo sob demanda, não estou conseguindo fazer pelo data_url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image: Esse e o esquema MVC]

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.loaddata = function(options) {// Settings
  var settings = $.extend({
   loading_gif_url : "https://zippy.gfycat.com/ImpoliteLivelyGenet.gif", //url to loading gif
   end_record_text : 'Não existe mais conteudo!', //no more records to load
   data_url   : 'controllers/conteudo-controller.php', //url to PHP page
   start_page   : 1 //initial page
  }, options);

  var el = this;
  loading  = false;
  end_record = false;
  contents(el, settings); //initial data load

  $(window).scroll(function() { //detact scroll
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()){ //scrolled to bottom of the page
    contents(el, settings); //load content chunk
   }
  });
 };
 //Ajax load function
 function contents(el, settings){
  var load_img = $('<img/>').attr('src',settings.loading_gif_url).addClass('loading-image'); //create load image
  var record_end_txt = $('<div/>').text(settings.end_record_text).addClass('end-record-info'); //end record text

  if(loading == false && end_record == false){
   loading = true; //set loading flag on
   el.append(load_img); //append loading image
   $.post( settings.data_url, {'page': settings.start_page}, function(data){ //jQuery Ajax post
    if(data.trim().length == 0){ //no more records
     el.append(record_end_txt); //show end record text
     load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
     end_record = true; //set end record flag on
     return; //exit
    }
    loading = false;  //set loading flag off
    load_img.remove(); //remove loading img
    el.append(data);  //append content
    settings.start_page ++; //page increment
   })
  }
 }

})(jQuery);

$("#results").loaddata();
```

```css
.wrapper{width: 500px;margin: 0 auto;font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
.wrapper > ul#results li{margin-bottom: 1px;background: #f9f9f9;padding: 20px;list-style: none;}
.loading-image {display: block;margin: 5px auto;}
.end-record-info {text-align: center;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;padding: 5px 0;background: #f9f9f9;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul id="results"><!-- results appear here as list --></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOpt. Explique melhor o erro que está acontecendo - o que específicamente não está funcionando? Aproveite e faça o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), ou leia sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)